# Additional condition in for each

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering: is there any possibility to add additional condition to for each?
I'm thinking about something like:

```
int i=0;
for(auto &it : list; i++)
    if(it.ID == 25)
        return i;
```

or

```
for(auto &it : list, int i=0; i++)
    if(it.ID == 25)
        return i;
```

Comment: Why not just use a traditional for loop at this point?

Comment: No.  Just add it within the body of the loop.

Comment: `boost::zip_iterator` together with some sequence glue could do this for you.  Something like: `for( auto pair : zip(list, sequence(0, infinity)) ) { if( pair.first == 25) return pair.second; }` syntax could be created with a bunch of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can use the old "normal" `for` loop for that:

```
auto iter = std::begin(list)
for (int i = 0; iter != std::end(list); ++iter, ++i)
{
    auto& it = *iter;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::find_if`:

```
const auto position = std::find_if(list.cbegin(), list.cend(), []((decltype(*list.cbegin()) value)
{
    return value.ID == 25;
});
return position - list.cbegin();
```

(Updated, now independent of container value_type)

Answer (score 1):

> Mandatory Reference: [Sean Parent's "Seasoning C++" talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning):
>
> #### *goal 1: Avoid raw loops*

In cases like these, abstract your algorithm!

This will come up more often, so it's worth making it generic:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename C, typename Pred>
   size_t index_if(C const& c, Pred&& pred)
{
    const auto f(begin(c)), l(end(c));

    auto match = std::find_if(f, l, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
    return (l==match) ? -1 : std::distance(f, match);
}
```

Now you can write your query:

```
int main()
{
    struct X { int ID; };
    const std::vector<X> v { {1},{2},{3},{25},{4},{5},{6},{42} };
    return index_if(v, [](X const& x) { return x.ID == 25; });
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd8e3bfef0a72a8e)**

---

PS. You might want a value-based version along with the predicate-based one:

```
template <typename C, typename V/* = typename C::value_type*/>
   size_t index_of(C const& c, V const v)
{
    const auto f(begin(c)), l(end(c));
    auto match = std::find(f, l, v);
    return (l==match) ? -1 : std::distance(f, match);
}
```

Comment: nice algorithm, but the OP does not compare an object of container::value_type with a constant container::value_type, but only one field. std::find does not work for this

Comment: @stefan just spotted it and changed my answer :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37315/discussion-between-sehe-and-stefan)

Comment: a little late, I watched the video but I don;t think that guy is right that you should blindly replace your loops with functions from the STL. These kind of mantras are dangerous, avoid this, avoid that .... You should always pay attention to the big picture and, maybe, a raw loop in 3 lines is the most performant solution sometimes, specially if you are blindly calling mamooth STL functions that by the way can have raw loops inside.

Comment: @rupps "blindly" whatever is never good. Your mantra is "avoid mantras". Also, you suggest that performance was the goal. 99% of the time performance is subordinate to correctness and maintainability.
Yes, "STL functions can have raw loops inside". No they cannot: by the very definition, they are _no longer raw_: You *cannot* write a loop condition wrong (off-by-one errors? mixed signed/unsigned comparison? name hiding? boundary cases (say std::rotate with middle equal to begin/end) etc), ...

Comment: you *cannot* forget about exception neutrality, you don't have to remember that since you switched from unordered to ordered sets you can have O(log n) instead of O(n) search etc. etc.
Your point "mamoth STL functions" ignores optimization.

Comment: So all in all: I'm not saying "never write raw loops". I have seen and written code that was more maintainable with raw loops. I just said (quote): "[...] abstract your algorithm [...] This will come up more often, so it's worth making it generic". That way you do the thinking, testing and documenting once, and you increase your productivity and lower your error rate in the future.